# Map datatype values were not showing up on page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to populate map datatype values on the page, but is not returning as expected.

```
teachersData = [];
for(var l=0;l<students.length;l++){
    var temp = students[l].trim().split('=');
    var mapTeacherDetail = new Map();
    mapTeacherDetail.set('teacherId', temp[0]);
    mapTeacherDetail.set('teacherName', temp[1]);
    if(temp[0] == ''){
           mapTeacherDetail.set('isTeacherIdEmpty', true);
        }else{
           mapTeacherDetail.set('isTeacherIdEmpty', false);
        }
        if(!isNextVal){
           isNextVal = true;
        }else{
           mapTeacherDetail.set('isOtherRec', true);
        }                         
        teachersData.push(mapOwnerDetail);
}
```

Out come in console is as shown below
[image]

Below is the html code

```
<template for:each={teachersData} for:item="items">
    <template for:each={items} for:item="teacher" >
          {teacher}
    </template>
</template>
```

Giving outcome on the page as shown below
[image]

When inspected the element it is as shown below

[image]

If I change the value of {teacher} to {teacher.teacherName} no data is returned as it is not in map format. It is in array of string format. I need to have it map format in order to fullfill the check criteria and other business logic stuff can be handled in JS component rather than on HTML.

If I update the code in html to below format

```
<template for:each={teachersData} for:item="items">
    {items}
</template>
```

On the page it shows [object Map].

Please suggest me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for asking your question, but I think we need a bit more detail to help. It would be useful to understand some of the why, so that we can help with the how. I'm assuming that you are wanting to use the teacher data in your component so that you can then use this in the HTML of your component, right? Is so, have you thought about using an an array of objects, rather than an array of maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `Map` the way you're trying to. You need plain objects.

```
let teacherDetail = {};
```

And then set each property:

```
teacherDetail.isTeacherIdEmpty = !!teacherId;
```

You can also do both at once:

```
let teacherData = {
  teacherId,
  isTeacherIdEmpty: !!teacherId,
  // etc
};
```

Also, a couple of pointers:

First, don't use `var`. It's subject to [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) which can lead to unforeseen consequences. `let` is now the preferred choice.

Second, prefer imperative programming using Array methods when you can, as they tend to be more legible.

```
teachersData = students.map(
   (student) => ({
      let temp = student.trim().split('=');
      let value = {
         teacherId: temp[0],
         isTeacherIdEmpty: !!temp[0]
      };
      return value;
   })
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @sfdcfox. It worked. These were good learning for me as I am new to this LWC.